# CellTable with Date Column

Tags: date, gwt, gwt-celltable

I am trying to build a CellTable Widget for time tracking. The first Column must represent all days for current month in following form

```
Fri, 1
Sat, 2
Sun, 3
Mon, 4
Tue, 5
…
```

etc. till the end of the month (28 -31 rows).

My code looks like that:

```
Column<Rec,String> dayColumn = new Column<Rec,String>(new TextCell())
{   
    @Override
    public String getValue(Rec rec) 
    {
        dayNr = DateTimeFormat.getFormat( "EE,d" ).format(new Date());
        return dayNr;    
    }
}; 

table.addColumn(dayColumn, "Date");
```

So can I see in this Column only Today-date in all cells.
How can I get all days of the month (1...28/30/31) in this Column each in its own cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be ideal if you prepared the list of Rec items with a Date variable.

### Declaring a Rec pojo with date

```
Class Rec{
 Date date;
 //getter and setters.
}
```

### Populate list of Rec items

```
List<Rec> recItems = new ArrayList<Rec>();

Date now = new Date();
int nowMonth = now.getMonth();
int nowYear = now.getYear();
List<Date> listOfDatesInThisMonth = new ArrayList<Date>();
Date beginningOfMonth = new Date(nowYear,nowMonth,1);
Date beginningOfNextMonth = new Date(nowYear,nowMonth+1,1);
Date start = beginningOfMonth;
while(start.before(beginningOfNextMonth)){
 listOfDatesInThisMonth.add(start);
 start = new Date(nowYear,nowMonth,start.getDate()+1);
}
for(Date date:listOfDatesInThisMonth){
 Rec recItem = new Rec();
 recItem.setDate(date);
 recItems.add(recItem );
}
```

### Rendering

```
Column<Rec,String> dayColumn = new Column<Rec,String>(new TextCell())
{   
    @Override
    public String getValue(Rec rec) 
    {
        dayNr = DateTimeFormat.getFormat( "EE,d" ).format(rec.getDate());
        return dayNr;    
    }
};
```

Comment: If it helped upvote. If it solved your problem close the question by selecting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ??

```
private static String getMonthsString() {
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
Date date = new Date() ;
 int i = date.getMonth();
   if(i==2)//feb {
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
       buffer.append(DateTimeFormat.getFormat( "EE,d" ).format( new Date(new Date().getTime() + ((1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*j)))));   
                }
            return buffer.toString(); 

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But so far I understand i<=30 means that each month has 30 days? And I need not 30 Columns, but 28...31 rows in the same Column

Answer (score 0):

In a Cell Table each row is one record. A month will have atleast 28 days. So you must build atleast 28 records and do setList or setData on the cell Table. A short code snippet is given below -

```
Date currentDate = new Date();

Map<Integer, String> daysMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
daysMap .put(0,"Sunday");
.
.
daysMap .put(6, "Saturday");

Map<Integer, Integer> monthMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
monthMap.put(0, 31);
.
.
monthMap.put(0, 31);

List<Rec> list = new ArrayList<Rec>();

for(int i=1;i <= monthMap.get(currentDate.getMonth());i++)
{
       list.add(new Rec( daysMap.get(currentDate.getDay())+" , "+ i ));
}


Column<Rec,String> dayColumn = new Column<Rec,String>(new TextCell())
{   
    @Override
    public String getValue(Rec rec) 
    {
        return rec.getDayDateString(); // which returns Friday, 1 etc.   
    }
}; 

table.addColumn(dayColumn, "Date");

ListDataProvider<Rec> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Rec>();

listDataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
listDataProvider.setList( list );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the dates of each month on the server side using java.util.Calendar

Comment: unfortunately java.util.Calendar is not compartible with gwt

Comment: This should be done on the server side, I do mention it in the answer. (Provided that the back end is written in java)

Answer (score 0):

Showing a scrollable list for dates is horrible usability. I would suggest using a DatePickerCell instead. It uses a date picker, so that the user can just click on the date to choose it.